# Multiple products per display

Tags: commerce

I'm working on a clothing store and I need to create a page type in which a model wears different pieces of clothes and users can see all the different products and add them separately to cart.

In other words, how could I have multiple products (of different kinds) on the same display, so that users can see the product of each product, choose sizes, etc., and add them to cart separately? (It's not a product bundle that you buy as a whole.) I've tried to create more than one product reference field, and I get multiple product-add-to-cart forms, but I can't have each product's price displayd separately. Is that possible? I can only display the price of the first product with the flag "Render fields from the referenced products when viewing this entity" checked.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least 3 options:

1. If you're requiring all of the products to be bought together, you could use [Commerce Bundle](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bundle) to create a Bundle Group product, and then add all of the individual bundle groups (e.g. a top, a bottom, and a pair of shoes) to it. This would then give you the ability to have all three products on a single page, but it'd require you to buy all 3 as a bundle.
2. You could create a node or a taxonomy page that simply references the node or products using entity or product reference fields. This would then give you multiple separate add to cart forms on a single page, (basically taking the three pages and combining them together).
3. Use [Commerce Add to Cart Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_extras) (or Commmerce's built-in views plugin) and build views which you could display on a node, panel, etc. Add to Cart Extras would allow you to build a form which would allow for bulk purchasing as well.